# How to bulk collect into a Type where UDT in subquery

Tags: plsql, subquery, oracle12c, user-defined-types, bulk-collect

I'm trying to create a collection of values for which i plan on running a FORALL DELETE FROM [table] on.
When i have a UDT in the subquery nothing seems to get bulk collected into the collection.

This does not seem to be working.

```
SELECT ATTR1
BULK COLLECT INTO tmpTBL1
FROM Table1
WHERE ATTR1 NOT IN (SELECT ATTR1 FROM TABLE(tmpPList)); --99% sure problem is here.
```

Have also confirmed that the column sizes in the object type are the same sizes in the Person table. (Thought padding might have been an issue.)

***Object Type***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type dbo.P_REC AS OBJECT
(
    ATTR1    VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
    ATTR2    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    ATTR3    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    ATTR4    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
);
```

***Collection Type***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE type dbo.P_REC_LIST is table of P_REC;
```

***Stored Procedure***

```
PROCEDURE Get_PRecList(tmpPList IN P_REC_LIST,
               resultCursor out sys_refcursor)
IS

TYPE CNsTable IS TABLE OF PERSON.ATTR1%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TYPE TmpTable IS TABLE OF P_REC INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

tmpTBL1        CNsTable;
Collection1    TmpTable;

BEGIN

    IF tmpPList.count > 0 THEN

    SELECT ATTR1
    BULK COLLECT INTO tmpTBL1
    FROM Table1
    WHERE ATTR1 NOT IN (SELECT ATTR1 FROM TABLE(tmpPList)); --99% sure problem is here.

    FOR indx IN 1 .. tmpTBL1.COUNT
    LOOP
        Collection1(Collection1.COUNT + 1) := tmpPList(indx);
    END LOOP;

    IF Collection1.COUNT > 0 THEN
        FORALL ind IN 1 .. Collection1.COUNT
            DELETE 
            FROM PERSON
            WHERE ATTR1 = Collection1(ind).ATTR1;
    END IF;
```

Mock Table Data

```
tmpPList 
 __________________________________________
|__attr1__||__attr2__||__attr3__||__attr4__|
   jdoe       John       Doe        abcd
   fmac      Frank       Mac        efgh
   wgab      Wayne       Gab        ijkl

Table1
 __________________________________________
|__attr1__||__attr2__||__attr3__||__attr4__|
   jdoe       John       Doe        abcd
   fmac       Frank      Mac        efgh
   wgab       Wayne      Gab        ijkl
   mkell      Mike       Kell       mnop

Table2
 __________________________________________
|__attr1__||__attr2__||__attr3__||__attr4__|
   mdoe       Mary       Doe        abcd
   jmac       John       Mac        efgh
   mgab       Mitch      Gab        ijkl
   mkell      Mike       Kell       mnop

tmpTBL1
 _________
|__attr1__|
  mkell

Collection1
 __________________________________________
|__attr1__||__attr2__||__attr3__||__attr4__|
   mkell      Mike       Kell       mnop

Before delete - Person
 __________________________________________
|__attr1__||__attr2__||__attr3__||__attr4__|
   jdoe       John       Doe        abcd
   fmac       Frank      Mac        efgh
   wgab       Wayne      Gab        ijkl
   mkell      Mike       Kell       mnop

After delete - Person
 __________________________________________
|__attr1__||__attr2__||__attr3__||__attr4__|
   jdoe       John       Doe        abcd
   fmac       Frank      Mac        efgh
   wgab       Wayne      Gab        ijkl
```

tmpTBL1 does not get populated with values when I use the TABLE(tmpPList).
I'm expecting there to be records removed from person.
Trying to find the ATTR1 that exists in PERSON but DO NOT exist in tmpPList.

***Update:***
Using: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was not here.

```
SELECT ATTR1
BULK COLLECT INTO tmpTBL1
FROM Table1
WHERE ATTR1 NOT IN (SELECT ATTR1 FROM TABLE(tmpPList));
```

But instead here. The entire for-loop was not required and the FORALL statement worked fine without it.

```
FOR indx IN 1 .. tmpTBL1.COUNT
LOOP
    Collection1(Collection1.COUNT + 1) := tmpPList(indx); 
END LOOP;
```